# How can I split a video file by Java

Tags: java, video-processing, xuggle

I wanna split a video file into several fragments which can be played individually. 
Is there any java library can be used in this situation?
Or if Xuggle can be used, can anyone give me an simple example. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A video file? There's quite a few video codecs, file formats. For a general solution try `ffmpeg` it's not a Java library but runs on all platforms.